# What do I need to have GUI to auto detect & connect to Wireless Network

Tags: software-recommendation, wireless, configuration

I am on LXDE + Minimal Ubuntu for sometime. I am lost at how to troubleshoot or connect to Wireless networks. So I am looking for a GUI tool, perhaps light-weight & relatively easy to use, that works with LXDE. It should handle listing of Wireless Networks & allow me to connect to them easily.

It should also allow me to default to a Wireless network when I startup my PC too.

**UPDATE: `network-manager-gnome` & `nm-applet`**

this seems to be one way. But I can't seem to have `nm-applet` start on boot.

I tried

```
sudo cp /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

Then reading another article, edited `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`

```
OnlyShowIn=LXDE;
```

Since I am using LXDE. But it still wont start ...

Comment: It do not require `sudo` to copy and do not require to be modified to start. To diagnose it edit the Exec= line to read `Exec=sh -c 'date >> ~/log; echo "Starting nm-applet" >>~/log; nm-applet --sm-disable'`, then go and read what you find in the file ~/log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`. The latter provide the `nm-applet` that goes in the system tray and allow to configure connections.

It used to work also with LXDE.

To start it at login, copy it to the personal autostart directory:

```
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

Comment: Ok, it works great. Except, how can I auto start it? I updated my question

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: hmm, isnt that same as what I did in my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, and it should work, unless you made something wrong. I also commented on your question to give an help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @enzotib, there is nothing in the log... what does this mean?

Comment: The log file exists and is empty (I do not think so), or it does not exists? Anyway, it means the desktop file is not even started, cannot say way: it is difficult to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid pulling in a bunch of Gnome dependencies (if you don't already have them), `wicd` is another option.  For bonus points, there's also a curses-based client (`wicd-curses`) that's really nice on a minimal install.

Comment: OK, only problem is how do I know what Encryption type to use? I know I am using WEP, I selected WEP Hex then it was stuck at obtaining IP address ... until I started `nm-applet`

Comment: It automatically picked the correct encryption type for me, I just had to supply the key.  Also, you probably don't want to have `network-manager` and `wicd` installed at the same time.  I'm still getting reacquainted with Linux, but I think they would conflict if both are trying to manage your network.  If it wasn't working until you started `nm-applet`, then `wicd` wasn't configured correctly.

Comment: I suppose with my connection active, I will be able to find out what kind of encryption I am using? Specifically, what kind of WEP. Also, I notice that `wicd` and `nm-applet` shows different signal strength. Do they use different metrics? I know I should remove 1 ... but for now, I'm curious

Comment: They might use different metrics, but signal strength can change so rapidly from varying conditions that just sampling at different intervals can yield different results.  Unfortunately, I'm not home with my Ubuntu-laptop and WiFi, so I can't be of more use in determining exactly what else you need to do right now.  Sorry.  One thing that swung me away from `network-manager` and towards `wicd`: I'm not smart enough to get `n-m` connected to a WPA-based WiFi from a command prompt, but `wicd` was *really* easy.

Comment: Also, any idea how to identify the type of WEP used? Hex, passphrase or something else. I think its hex. But wicd got stuck at Obtaining IP